# Java: Timer (wait x seconds)

Tags: java, timer

I have a simple GUI that can save and get some data out of an .doc file.

When i press a save button, i have a label that says "Succes" or "Error" via label.setText();

Update: The code is meant to be ran in a FXMLDocumentController (built på SceneBuilder)

I want the label to go back to being empty ("") after 3 seconds..

I have tried:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);               
    } 
 catch(InterruptedException ex) {
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

}

but is it like, that the sleep-function freezes the whole GUI so i can't interact with it while it's sleeping. How do i set up an timer that does not affect usability? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a TimerTask which is started after 3 seconds. 
This TimerTask has to execute the code which uses gui components via Platform.runLater(new Runnable())

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    label.setText("");
                }
            });

        }
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: I don't get a compiling error for this, but the followring runtime error: Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-0

Comment: Oh. If you are using javafx you must handle this with Platform.runLater() to run your code in the gui thread. I updated my post

Comment: Thanks for your time:) I get this compiling error now: error: cannot find symbol
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  symbol: variable Platform

Comment: Did you use the right Platform class? javafx.application.Platform

Comment: Yes: import javafx.application.Platform;

Answer (score 1):

```
class runnable implements Runnable {
    private Object obj;
    public runnable(Object obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            this.obj.setText("");//right here just execute your method
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!"); //your code here
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object myObject;
        (new Thread(new runnable(myObject))).start();
    }
}
```

You could launch another thread to handle this.  Just do your processing in the other thread. Sleep for 3 seconds then clear the lbl.

Here is an example showing how it works:

```
class runnable implements Runnable {
    Test test;
    public runnable(Test test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            this.test.test = "test2";
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

}

public class Test {
    public String test = "test";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.test);
        (new Thread(new runnable(test))).start();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        System.out.println(test.test);
    }
}
```

************************************************************UPDATE*************************************************************

```
class runnable implements Runnable {
    Test test;
    public runnable(Test test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            this.test.label.setText("This is a test.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

}

public class Test {
    public String test = "test";
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Test test = new Test();
        test.label.setText("Test");
        test.button.setText("Test Button");
        test.button.setSize(50, 50);
        test.frame.setSize(500, 500);
        test.frame.add(test.button);
        test.frame.add(test.label);
        test.frame.setVisible(true);
        test.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });
        (new Thread(new runnable(test))).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: If OP needs a timer in Swing than this is not the best way as Swing provides its own timers. Not to mention that the code from other thead will not be ran on dispatch thread.

Comment: 1. Why to use threads if there is much simpler way to do that? 2. The code in the second thread must not update Swing unless you make it invoke on EDT (another Runnable) so the example above is wrong unless you add that.

Comment: I was trying to use your code - but i am calling the method from my FXML DocumentController.java (which controls all input/output to my GUI labels) - how do i acces the label.setText() from the runnable class? :/

Comment: @CasperTL I updated my post look at the constructor and how I pass in the object.  Just use your label object instead of generic Object like I used I was just giving an example...

Comment: @brso05 Thanks! I will just try it, give me a minute :)

Comment: @CasperTL Your welcome...I posted an example showing how it works since you are passing the object by reference it will actually modify the original object.

Comment: @brso05 Hm.. I copied your code and changed the Test to a label. No compiling errors.. But when i run it, it freezes the gui for 4 seconds :/ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4

Comment: @CasperTL Hey man I just posted new code with a swing gui run this code exactly as I have it and you should see how it works.  Use the code under ***Update***

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with GUI because the code is sleeping in event dispatch thread which is responsible for handling GUI events and so it's blocked. Use this Swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead.

The given example there is simple. I include the comments.

```
  int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

  //Create action listener which listens for the event generated by the timer
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          Place here code to execute when the time runs out.
      }
  };
  //Simply create a timer with the created listener and start it.
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: I am not so experienced in java ( yet :D ), so could you give me an example of code for waiting 3 seconds and then performing a label.setText(""); ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Thread.sleep()`. Instantiate a `javax.swing.Timer` and have it do an event callback. If you want to keep it in the same method, call `wait()`, and then have the event handler call `notify()`, which will resume the program. However, you probably don't need to do that; you can just remove the text directly using the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will have to use [threading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). In case you are using Swing you can use a Swing Timer. The code will look something like this. Put this code where you are 'saving' the file.

```
  int delay = 3000; 
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //Empty the label here. This code will be called once the timeout of three seconds has been passed
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your are blocking the UI thread. It cannot update anything and the main loop breaks. You can accomplish your goal with a `timer` object as others have answered, or if you don't want to you could implement your own thread to do the same.